# Scheduled task to run every 3 days at given time

Tags: java, web-applications, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz 2 scheduler for scheduling tasks. Below is what I need.

1. schedule the job when the user click on a button.
2. The job should be scheduled to run at 8 AM, every 3 days.

Below is how I coded it. It will execute (with its scheduler of course) once the user click on a button in web app)

```
Trigger passportTrigger1 = newTrigger()
                 .withIdentity(passportTriggerKey1)
                 .withSchedule(simpleSchedule().withIntervalInHours(3*24).repeatForever()) 
                 .startAt(todayAt(8,0,0)).build();
```

However you can see that I have used `startAt(todayAt(8,0,0))`. What happens if the user turned on the scheduler after 8.00 AM today? The job will be scheduled immediately or it will never get scheduled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also check the current time: if it's before 8am `startAt(todayAt(8, 0, 0)` else `startAt(tomorrowAt(8, 0, 0))`.